# Angular Router: Redirect Old System URL to New URL

Tags: angular, router

Using Angular 12+

Our old system had ASPX pages and different query string values. Our new system is Angular-based so the ASPX page links/query string no longer exist. Is there a way to extend the Router so that when an ASPX page request comes, it is redirected to a translated set of query params and the correct Angular route? There would be a large number of permutations so we need to run the URL thru a logical re-writer, not just a Router map.

For now, I have a 404Component that looks at the URL, then decides the new URL, and does a redirect.

Customers have the old ASPX pages bookmarked so need to be supported.

Comment: Maybe a guard on the default route?

Comment: This mapping should not be the responsibility of the Angular app though IMHO.

Comment: Provide examples of old URLs and their corresponding new URLs so we can give you sample code. You can also map them in IIS or any other webserver you are using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a implementation based on `CanActivate` Guard

Create a Redirect service which will determine URL to redirect and return URL final destination URL (sample implementation below)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, CanDeactivate } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class RedirectGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(public router: Router) {}

    canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean> {
        const originalRequestUrl = state.url;

        if(this.isOldUrl(originalRequestUrl)) {
            this.router.navigate([this.getRedirectUrl(originalRequestUrl)]);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    isOldUrl(url: string): boolean {
        // pattern check on URL to determine if url needs redirect
        return true;
    }

    getRedirectUrl(url: string): string {
        // logic to return redirect-url of final destination
        // returning same url for now
        return url;
    }

}
```

Add (or replace map) this to your router map (catch all map definition)

```
{
    path: '**',
    canActivate: [ RedirectGuard ],
    redirectTo: '/'
}
```

Now, any unmatched URL (`**`) should now be resolved by `RedirectGuard` service class